# Box Order Animations

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, css-animations

I have this set of boxes that are ordered in a row, each box has value to it and background color. Eventually, the box changes its position and I want to animate that.

This is what I was able to do **code below** or ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/MarioRozic/pen/yGvMGP?editors=0110)), and its fine, but when I add 5 more boxes (need to have 6), the animation (transition) sometimes just skip itself and box kinda just pop into that place, [you can see that here](https://codepen.io/MarioRozic/pen/REQgpQ?editors=0110).

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

const BOX_COLOR = {
  1: "red",
  2: "blue",
  3: "green",
  4: "black",
  5: "orange",
  6: "yellow"
};


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: [1]
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {                 
    setInterval(() => {
      let newArr = shuffle(this.state.value)
      this.setState({ value: newArr})
    }, 2000);
  }
  
  render() {
     let order = this.state.value.map((BoxValue, BoxOrder) => { // BoxOrder is position of the box
      let classColor = BOX_COLOR[BoxValue]; // because each number has different color
      let classOrder = null; // and this should dictate on what position should that box be
      let randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 // generate random box position 
      switch (randomPosition) {
        case 1:
          classOrder = "first";
          break;
        case 2:
          classOrder = "second";
          break;
        case 3:
          classOrder = "third";
          break;
        case 4:
          classOrder = "fourth";
          break;
        case 5:
          classOrder = "fifth";
          break;
        case 6:
          classOrder = "sixth";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      return (
        <div key={BoxValue} className={["box", classColor, classOrder].join(" ")}>
          {BoxValue}
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
    <div className="container">
       {order} 
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid #666;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  border: 5px solid #999;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 700ms ease-in-out;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.first {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.second {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

.third {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}

.fourth {
  transform: translateX(300px);
}

.fifth {
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

.sixth {
  transform: translateX(500px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

What do you think, what is the problem here, I just want that animation to be smooth as when it is only one box?

Comment: I tried your codepen on FF64.0, cannot reproduce, which browser are you using?

Comment: Hmm ...Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.98)

Comment: I don't see any issue either, unless your issue is with having two white fields next to each other, before they get populated?

Comment: Well that too, but I am just not satisfied with how animations perform if there is one, sometimes box just pops into that place no matter where it was before.

Comment: Nope sry, I already have something like that in my box class

Comment: this doesn't look so bad: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoZeJx?editors=0110

Comment: Well, that looks the same as my example with 6 boxes :(, I want to prevent that white box of showing and Box just snap into some position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186130/discussion-between-vickel-and-mario-rozic).

Comment: U pythonu ništa ne trza haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using `BoxValue` as `BoxOrder` and visa-versa. Just switch them where you have used it in render method.
Replace `BoxValue` to `BoxOrder + 1` and replace `BoxOrder + 1` to `BoxValue`. (I think at 3 places, I have added comment)

See the Snippet below:

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

const BOX_COLOR = {
  1: "red",
  2: "blue",
  3: "green",
  4: "black",
  5: "orange",
  6: "yellow"
};


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {                 
    setInterval(() => {
      let newArr = shuffle(this.state.value)
      this.setState({ value: newArr})
    }, 2000);
  }
  
  render() {
     let order = this.state.value.map((BoxValue, BoxOrder) => { // BoxOrder is position of the box
      let classColor = BOX_COLOR[BoxOrder+1]; // because each number has different color
//CHANGED BoxValue TO BoxOrder+1
      let classOrder = null; // and this should dictate on what position should that box be
      let randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 // generate random box position 
      switch (BoxValue) {//CHANGED BoxOrder+1 TO BoxValue
        case 1:
          classOrder = "first";
          break;
        case 2:
          classOrder = "second";
          break;
        case 3:
          classOrder = "third";
          break;
        case 4:
          classOrder = "fourth";
          break;
        case 5:
          classOrder = "fifth";
          break;
        case 6:
          classOrder = "sixth";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      return (
        <div key={BoxOrder +1} className={["box", classColor, classOrder].join(" ")}>
          {BoxOrder +1}
        </div>
      );
      //CHANGED BoxValue TO BoxOrder+1 
    });
    return (
    <div className="container">
       {order} 
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid #666;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  border: 5px solid #999;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 700ms ease-in-out;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.first {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.second {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

.third {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}

.fourth {
  transform: translateX(300px);
}

.fifth {
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

.sixth {
  transform: translateX(500px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

You can also test it [here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/vvddom?editors=0110)

Comment: that looks like the solution to the problem asked!

Comment: Sir this is exactly what I wanted, Thank you, but I still don't understand why does that make a difference

Comment: If you see developer tool, I am not changing the divs. I am just changing the class. So div value will always be 1,2,3..6 and class will be random sixth, third, first, second.. And that's where you were making mistake. :) You can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aI6Q.png